# How to show model and view differently in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I am implementing a functionality in AngularJS.
When the user enters 1.5, In view, it should show as 01:30, but when I fetch this scope value in the controller it should return as 1.5.
I have added code in plunker. Please find here.

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="wbTimeConverter"> 

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="wbNumberToTime.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <input type="text" md-maxlength="5" wb-number-to-time-convert ng-model="task" placeholder="task" ng-blur="onDataChange();" />

  <input type="text" md-maxlength="5" wb-number-to-time-convert ng-model="project" placeholder="project" ng-blur="onDataChange();" />

  <br>
  <label>Task : {{task}}</label><br>
  <label>Project : {{project}}</label><br>
  <label>TotalResult : {{totalHours}}</label>
</body>

</html>
```

**Controller - Script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('wbTimeConverter', []);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.onDataChange = onDataChange;

function onDataChange(){
  console.log("res");
  $scope.totalHours= parseFloat($scope.task) + parseFloat($scope.project, 10);
}


});
```

**directive:**

```
// 'use strict';
// /**
//  * This directive is convert number into hours and minutes format-HH:MM
//  * This will trigger when we change value in input element and gives respective value in time format
//  */

app.directive('wbNumberToTimeConvert', function ($filter, $browser) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var listener = function () {
        var value = $element.val();
        var result = convertToTime(value);
        $element.val(result.timeFormat);
        $element.attr('attr-hrs', result.decimalFormat);
      };

      // This runs when we update the text field
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
        return viewValue;
      });

      $element.bind('change', listener);
      $element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        // FIXME to handle validations
      });

      $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
        $browser.defer(listener);
      });

      function convertToTime(value) {
        var res = { 'timeFormat': '', 'decimalFormat': '' };
        var inputValue = value;
        if (inputValue.indexOf(':') > -1) {
          inputValue = convertToNumberFormat(inputValue);
          res.decimalFormat = inputValue;
        } else {
          res.decimalFormat = value;
        }

        inputValue = inputValue.split('.');
        var hoursValue = inputValue[0];
        if (inputValue.length > 1) {

          var hrs = parseInt(hoursValue, 10);
          hrs = isNaN(hoursValue) ? 0 : hrs;
          hrs = (hrs < 10) ? '0' + hrs : hrs;

          var minutesValue = inputValue[1];
          var mins = parseInt(minutesValue, 10);
          mins = (minutesValue.length < 2 && (mins < 10)) ? Math.round(mins * 6) : Math.round(mins * 0.6);
          mins = (mins < 10) ? ('0' + mins) : mins;
          inputValue = hrs + ':' + mins;
          res.timeFormat = inputValue;
        } else {

          inputValue = (parseInt(inputValue, 10) < 10) ? '0' + parseInt(inputValue, 10) : parseInt(inputValue, 10);
          inputValue = inputValue + ':' + '00';
          res.timeFormat = inputValue;
        }
        return res;
      }

      function convertToNumberFormat(inputValue) {
        var timeValue = inputValue.split(':');
        var hours = parseInt(timeValue[0], 10);
        var mins = parseInt(timeValue[1], 10);
        if (isNaN(hours)){
          hours = '00';
        }
        if (isNaN(mins)) {
          mins = '00';
        }
        mins = Math.round(mins / 0.6);
        if (mins < 10) {
          mins = '0' + mins;
        }
        var number = hours + '.' + mins;
        return number;
      }

    }

  };
});
```

Here is the plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/76lwlnQlGC0wfjixicCK?p=preview

On textbox blur, it is working fine of value differ in View and Controller on first time and from second time on blur in textbox, it is showing same value 01:30 in both view and controller. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please provide some code to see what you are actually doing.

Comment: Please put some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your input inside the ng-model `myValue` and call a function `format(value)` to display what you need

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myValue = "1.5";
  $scope.format = function(value) {
    var hrs = parseInt(Number(value));
    var min = Math.round((Number(value) - hrs) * 60);
    return hrs + ':' + min;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="myValue">
  <br>Formatted Value : {{format(myValue)}}
  <br>Base value : {{myValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, It is better option but I am using directive. I need to call directive.

Comment: @AshokGurram You did not mention that you are working with directive. Show us your current code

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy using a directive! Take this as an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/474/)

If you have a directive that requires ngModelController you can manipulate the viewValue really easily.

ngModelController has two properties that we're interested in, $modelValue and $viewValue. $modelValue is the value that you use on the scope and $viewValue is the one the user sees.

ngModelController also has a property $formatters which is an array of formatters that convert a modelValue to viewValue. So if the modelValue changes on the side of the controller it will go through the formatters until the end, and this will change the viewValue. If you want to create your own formatter, simply add it the array!

```
//This formatter will convert the modelValue to display as uppercase in the viewValue
ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) { 
    if (modelValue) {
        return modelValue.toUpperCase();
    }
});
```

but the $formatters property only works for when the modelValue gets changed, so if the user is typing something into the input field, the viewValue is getting changed, the easiest way to handle this is to attach to the onBlur event in which we will alter the viewValue using another function provided by the ngModel controller. $setViewValue(value) will change the viewValue. If you change the viewValue in the directive, the view won't automatically update, so you need to call the $render function provided by the ngModelController

```
element.on('blur', function() {
   ngModelController.$setViewValue(convertDoubleToTimeString(ngModelController.$modelValue));
   ngModelController.$render();
});
```

For more information about this you can read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

EDIT:

In this example I haven't written a parser that converts a viewValue (1:30) to a modelValue (1,5). So let's add one. I also have an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/480/)

```
ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
    if (viewValue && viewValue.indexOf(':') < 0) {
        return viewValue;
    } else {
        return convertTimeStringToDouble(viewValue)
    }
});
```

Unshifting the parsers onto the $parsers array means it will be the first one to execute, this isn't really necessary, but why not, eh?

There are other ways of not changing the modelValue when the viewValue changes, but this one is the most correct one.

An alternative would be to just set the $viewValue directly without going through $setViewValue().

```
//ngModelController.$setViewValue(ngModelController.$modelValue.toUpperCase());
ngModelController.$viewValue = ngModelController.$modelValue.toUpperCase();
```

In that last line, it wont go through the usual steps of going through all the parsers and validators, so it's the less ideal solution.

Comment: I have tried with above provided fiddler. Even this solution causing the same issue. At first time, in view it is displaying as 02:30 and in controller as 2.5, but on editing value in textbox, I am getting same value in both controller and view as "02:30".

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function in controller to return the calucalted value and in html you can call that function and pass the scope variable.

```
$scope.calculate = function(value){
     var calculatedValue = /*Your operation*/;
     return calculatedValue;
}

<input type="text" ng-model="value"\>
<p>{{calculate(value)}}</p>
```

If you want real time update of the calculated value with respect to the input value then you can use another scope variable to store the calculate value.

```
$scope.calculate = function(value){
     $scope.calculatedValue = /*Your operation*/;
}

<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-change="calculate(value)"\>
<p>{{calculatedValue}}</p>
```